# Ubuntu 12.04 on Intel NUC5CPYH

Tags: 12.04, graphics, intel-nuc

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on intel NYC5CPYH using usb. Display was good when booted from live disk, but after installation it is giving an error of low graphics mode and after this it freezes. There is no way even to go to console. Is there any way I can get graphics settings when booted via live usb stick and use it to solve the low graphics issue. The monitor in this case is a 48" LED tv.

Comment: Why 12.04? You may have more luck with a newer Ubuntu release.

Comment: I want to run xibo client on this and last supported version for xibo client is 12.04. In fact I was running ubuntu 15.04 on same machine prior to this.

Comment: Using 15.04 on the NUC5CPYH, did you have any special problems ? or everything worked well ?

Comment: there were no problems with 15.04 running on this NUC, just that it would not shutdown properly. This caused it not to boot properly next time this was switched on as it would ask to check hdd

Answer (score 0):

I have the same NUC. You will need a reasonably recent kernel that supports **Intel HD Graphics (Braswell)** which is inbuilt in your NUC's CPU ([Intel Celeron N3050](http://ark.intel.com/products/87257/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N3050-2M-Cache-up-to-2_16-GHz)) - I think support was added in 4.2, but it could be also 4.1. These kernels are not available in standard repositories for Ubuntu 12.04, so you will have to head over to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and select one of the 4.x kernels, download the .deb packages relevant to your system (in your case, amd64 of the "generic" variety, low-latency is not normally recommended) and install them with `dpkg -i`. For example:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5-wily/linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.5.0-040500-generic_4.5.0-040500.201603140130_amd64.deb
```

After installing the packages, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. The graphics should work fine now.

Comment: Actually I did manage to boot it properly after creating a minimal xorg.conf file. I did this when booted from USB. After this I was able to boot properly with 12.04.

Comment: That is very interesting, could you please post your xorg.conf here?

Comment: Actually it did not workout for me on 12.04 as the xibo client for which i installed 12.04 was not supported any more on ubuntu and I had issues running it even on 12.04. So after this trial I upgraded to 14.04. Any way I do not have xog.conf file that I used. But what I did was boot directly into command line and when X server was not running issued sudo X -configure to create xorg.conf.new file. After renaming this file to xorg.conf and moving it to /etc/X11 just rebooted the machine to GUI mode